# Connect on MongoDB under AmazonEC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I'm starting with AmazonEC2 and created a security group with port 27017 open, but when I try to connect using "MongoClient" (java) I got the following output, can someone help me?

I'm also using Amazon Linux, and already tried to check to MongoDB documentation (https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/)

```
Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ec2-54-233-146-156.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more
```

Follow below my security group policies print screen:

[Security group policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27944.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check your mongodb config and ensure that the bind IP is not set to 127.0.0.1 and listens to external connections
2. See if you can connect to mongo locally on that port
3. Take a look at this if the above two don't fix your issue https://serverfault.com/a/347272/269101

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked and my MongoDB isn't set to listen external connections.